# How do you uncompress a split volume zip in Java?

Tags: java, zip

I need to reassemble a 100-part zip file and extract the content.  I tried simply concatenating the zip volumes together in an input stream but that does not work.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK the ZIP format doesn't have built-in splitting support like RAR does. What happens if you join them with something like `cat file.zip.001 file.zip.002 ... file.zip.100 file.zip` and then extract it using a ZIP utility?

Comment: What "does not work"? What error or exception are you getting?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Multivolume support in ZIP files has been there for a while, see _V. General Format of a .ZIP file_ in [the spec](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code you can start from. It extracts a single file entry from the multivolume zip archive:

```
package org.test.zip;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream is = new ZipInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(
            Arrays.asList(new FileInputStream("test.zip.001"), new FileInputStream("test.zip.002"), new FileInputStream("test.zip.003")))));
        try {
            for(ZipEntry entry = null; (entry = is.getNextEntry()) != null; ) {
                OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(entry.getName()));
                try {
                    final int bufferSize = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    for(int readBytes = -1; (readBytes = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > -1; ) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    }
                    os.flush();
                } finally {
                    os.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a note to make it more dynamic -- 100% based on mijer code below.

```
    private void CombineFiles (String[] files) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Vector<FileInputStream> v = new Vector<FileInputStream>(files.length);
    for (int x = 0; x < files.length; x++)
        v.add(new FileInputStream(inputDirectory + files[x]));

    Enumeration<FileInputStream> e = v.elements();

    SequenceInputStream sequenceInputStream = new SequenceInputStream(e);

    ZipInputStream is = new ZipInputStream(sequenceInputStream);
    try {
        for (ZipEntry entry = null; (entry = is.getNextEntry()) != null;) {
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(entry.getName()));
            try {
                final int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                for (int readBytes = -1; (readBytes = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > -1;) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                os.flush();
            } finally {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To just concatenate the segment data did not work for me. In this case the segments had been created with Linux command-line zip (InfoZip version 3.0):

```
> zip -s 5m data.zip -r data/
```

Segment files named `data.z01, data.z02, ..., data.zip` was created.

The first segment `data.z01` contained the spanning signature 0x08074b50, as described in the Zip File Format Specification by PKWARE. The presence of these 4 bytes made Java ZipInputStream ignore all entries in the archive. The central registry in the last segment also contained extra segment information compared to a non-split archive but that did not cause ZipInputStream any problems.

All I had to do was to skip the spanning signature. The following code will extract entries both from an archive that have been segmented with `zip -s` and from a zip file that have been split by the Linux `split` commad, like this: `split -d -b 5M data.zip data.zip.`. The code is based on szhem's.

```
public class ZipCat {
    private final static byte[] SPANNING_SIGNATURE = {0x50, 0x4b, 0x07, 0x08};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<InputStream> asList = new ArrayList<>();            
        byte[] buf4 = new byte[4];
        PushbackInputStream pis = new PushbackInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[0]), buf4.length);
        asList.add(pis);
        if (pis.read(buf4) != buf4.length) {
            throw new IOException(args[0] + " is too small for a zip file/segment");
        }
        if (!Arrays.equals(buf4, SPANNING_SIGNATURE)) {
            pis.unread(buf4, 0, buf4.length);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            asList.add(new FileInputStream(args[i]));
        }

        try (ZipInputStream is = new ZipInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(asList)))) {
            for (ZipEntry entry = null; (entry = is.getNextEntry()) != null;) {
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    new File(entry.getName()).mkdirs();
                } else {
                    try (OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(entry.getName()))) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int count = -1;
                        while ((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            os.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```