# Unzipping a multi-part zip file volumes using Java

Tags: java, archive, unzip, compression

I need to unzip a set of files that are a zip archive.  This isn't a set of zip files, this is one big zip file that has been broken up into multiple zip files based on a size requirement.

For example if you have a 2.5MB zip file and your mail system only supports 1MB files, you can ask Zip to create 3 files of at most 1MB.

So it creates a.zip.001, a.zip.002, a.zip.003 ... different libraries name them differently but essentially they all work the same way.

How do you unzip this in java?  It doesn't look like the compression libs in std supports this.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried chilkat which seems to have a lot of features but it does not support multi-file archives.  Not even on the todo list at this point.

Comment: How was the zip file broken into parts?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116443/how-do-you-uncompress-a-split-volume-zip-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate all the files into a single file and then extract the single file. Something like:

```
    File dir = new File("D:/arc");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
            "d:/arc/archieve-full.zip"));
    FileInputStream fis = null;
        Set<String> files = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (String fname : dir.list()) {
            files.add(fname);
        }
        for (String fname : files) {
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), fname));
            byte[] b = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(b);
            fos.write(b);
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            fos.flush();
        }
    }
    fos.close();
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("d:/arc/archieve-full.zip");
    /*extract files from zip*/
```

Update: used a `TreeSet` to sort the file names, as `dir.list()` doesn't guarantee alphabetical order.

Comment: If you're using Java SE 7, I recommend using ARM (try(...){}) instead of closing streams manually.

Comment: Although not exactly the same code, I did try this and it broke.  Concatenating seems to break the zip.  I "THINK" each file has its own header so that the system knows which part number it is which shouldn't be part of the stream.

Comment: @awm I tried with a zip compressed using 7zip and it worked fine. Make sure that the folder that you use contains only the zip files. There was a problem with the order of the files, but I fixed it in this update.