# Android: How to unzip a file splitted in parts

Tags: android, split, unzip

I want to unzip a file that is splitted in parts (file.part1, file.part2, file.part3...).
I had all the parts in the same folder. In internet I only found examples of how to unzip a single file.

Does someone know if there is an API to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compression APIs are unchanged from Java on Android, AFAIK. And in Java you can unzip multivolume files easily enough. I'm posting some Java code, which you should be able to run on Android with some minor (if any) modifications.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream is = new ZipInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(
        Arrays.asList(new FileInputStream("test.zip.001"), new FileInputStream("test.zip.002"), new FileInputStream("test.zip.003")))));
    try {
        for(ZipEntry entry = null; (entry = is.getNextEntry()) != null; ) {
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(entry.getName()));
            try {
                final int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                for(int readBytes = -1; (readBytes = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > -1; ) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                os.flush();
            } finally {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

}

The code is from an older SO question, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117538/1069068).